# How do I uncouple an angular directive and make it generic for different models?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dry

I have an angular directive that I'm using to make a table sortable (code example from https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/table/examples#complete)

In the example below, the sortable directive becomes coupled to my model, in this case Students, because SortColumn is using keyof Student.

```
import { Directive, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Student } from 'src/app/models/student.model';

export type SortColumn = keyof Student | '';
export type SortDirection = 'asc' | 'desc' | '';

const rotate: { [key: string]: SortDirection } = { asc: 'desc', desc: '', '': 'asc' };

export interface SortEvent {
    column: SortColumn;
    direction: SortDirection;
}

@Directive({
    selector: 'th[sortable]',
//  standalone: true,
    host: {
        '[class.asc]': 'direction === "asc"',
        '[class.desc]': 'direction === "desc"',
        '(click)': 'rotate()',
    },
})
export class NgbdSortableHeader {
    @Input() sortable: SortColumn = '';
    @Input() direction: SortDirection = '';
    @Output() sort = new EventEmitter<SortEvent>();

    rotate() {
        this.direction = rotate[this.direction];
        this.sort.emit({ column: this.sortable, direction: this.direction });
    }
}
```

I have a number of different tables that I need to use for other objects, and I need to make this directive generic so that I could provide the model from the component that this is a @ViewChildren of... How can I pass that from the parent component?

Or is there a better way to keep this DRY?

Comment: Make the class have a generic type, most of the component will then work as expected. You could also look into ngTemplateGuard